# How do I format these attributes into a specific date string variable for use in my query?

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have this element in my XML file:

```
<MeetingDate Day="29" DayShort="Thu" DayFull="Thursday" Month="4" MonthShort="Apr" MonthFull="April" Year="2021">29 April 2021</MeetingDate>
```

Using XSLT1 I would like to build a variable from three of the paramaters:

- `Year`
- `Month`
- `Day`

But I want the month and day to zero padded. Take for example the values 29, 4, 2021 then I want a variable to result in:

```
2021-04-29
```

This is because I need to be able to use this value in my subsequent query:

```
  <!-- Now we need to see if they are still available for this actual date -->
  <!-- MeetingDate @Year @Month @Day -->
  <xsl:variable name="strDate">2021-04-29</xsl:variable>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="count($PubDB/msa:PublisherDatabase/msa:Publishers/msa:Publisher[msa:Name=$strName]/msa:Availability/msa:DatesNotAvailable/msa:Date[$strDate])=0">
      <xsl:text>Still available for this date</xsl:text>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <em>
        <xsl:text>Not available for this date</xsl:text>
      </em>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
```

At the moment I put static text into the path. Note that I am in the correct context to just get the values of `MeetingDate/@Year` etc. in my XSL script. So how to we turn:

- `MeetingDate/@Year`
- `MeetingDate/@Month`
- `MeetingDate/@Day`

Into `YYYY-MM-DD` variable for using in my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context is not quite clear. Try something like:

```
<xsl:variable name="strDate">
    <xsl:value-of select="MeetingDate/@Year"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(MeetingDate/@Month, '-00')"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(MeetingDate/@Day, '-00')"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

Comment: That was exactly what I needed. Thank you verymuch.